# How to store run-results from QTP to word file?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

After I run my scripts in UFT, I want to store results in a word document that will have the same name as my tests or be relevant to test, so I can easily differentiate which result belong to which test.
Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the code:

```
Dim oWord

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

oWord.Documents.Add

oWord.ActiveDocument.Saveas "C:\Users\Desktop\RunResults\TestForWordDocResults2"

Dim oWordTestPath 

oWordTestPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\AutomationScripts\TestForWordDocResults"

' Launch QuickTest

Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") ' Create the Application object

qtApp.Launch ' Start QuickTest

qtApp.Visible = True ' Make the QuickTest application visible 

' Run the Test

qtApp.Open oWordTestPath, False ' Open the test 

Set qtResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") 'Create the Run Results Options object 

testResults = "C:\Users\Desktop\RunResults" 

' Original location for the test results.

qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = testResults ' Specify the location to save the test results.

oWordTestPath.Run qtResultsOpt, True ' Run the test and wait until end of the test run 

' Close QuickTest Professional

qtApp.Quit
```

What this code does:
it creates Word document, but doesn't store run results.

P.S. I want to store run-results using driver script, not "options" in UFT

Answer (score 1):

UFT provides options to export run result in three different formats.

- **`HTML`**
- **`PDF`**
- **`DOC`**

All you have to do is:

Go to **`Options --> Run Sessions`** (from General tab)
Check the box for **`Automatically export run results when run session ends`**
Click on **`Configure`**
Select the **`Export Type`** as **`Doc`**
Make necessary changes about the details you want to export
Specify the **`Export Location`**
Uncheck the box for **`Export run results only if run session fails`** if you want to export result in all cases
Click **`OK`**

Now every time you'll execute the script, UFT will store the run result for you on specified location.

**Note:**
You won't be able export **`Data, Screen Recorder and Log Tracking`** information.